# Display hidden div for non-javascript users

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a form with a div section that is hidden (using CSS property: `display: none`) unless someone selects a particular element from a list, in which case I use jQuery to show it.

This works great unless someone has JavaScript disabled on their browser, in which case the div remains hidden regardless of their selection.

I have tried to solve the problem using  (with `text/html` type) and `<noscript>` tags as follows:

```html
    <noscript> <div id="extra" style="display:block"></noscript>
    <script type="text/html">
    <div id="extra" style="display:none">
    </script>
  
     ...
 
    </div>
```

This does not work when JS is enabled, as it appears that the browser (tested on Chrome 32 and Safari 6) just ignores the script with type html.

Is there a better (or correct) way to do this?

Comment: You have to put JavaScript in a script tag, you can't just drop HTML in there.

Comment: @j08691: If you put a type on it, you can put all kinds of things in a script tag other than JavaScript. But I can't see any reason at all to put HTML in one...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use JavaScript to hide the div in the first place. Then you know it will be visible for users who have JavaScript disabled.

```
<div id="extra"></div>
<script>
document.getElementById("extra").style.display = "none";
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. It's so obvious when you're told the answer. Eloquent solution.

Comment: @Josh: Thanks. I prefer [CodeMonk's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21605486/157247), though. :-)

Answer (score 1):

here's a video tutorial on how this can be done with jQuery: http://screenr.com/ya7

**Code:**

```
<body class="noscript">
<script>
$('body').removeClass('noscript');
</script>
</body>
```

And then just hide the relevant elements under `body.noscript` accordingly

**Referenced from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577598/how-to-hide-parts-of-html-when-javascript-is-disabled)**

Comment: I like this a **lot** better than my off-the-cuff above. Then the CSS just applies according to whether body has the style. And I *knew* this pattern (Moderizr, etc.), but still didn't think of it when answering above.

Comment: Very clean and smart. Thank you.